# How do I run the top command with a child process on node.js without getting a 'stdout maxBuffer exceeded' from the terminal

Tags: node.js, linux

Im trying to create a REST API that gets the metrics from a VM but i can't seem to run my child process without getting 'stdout maxBuffer exceeded'. This is my code

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');


exec('top', (error, stdout, stderr) => {

    if (error) {

      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return;
     }

    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);

    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`top` (with it's default arguments) is going to keep writing to `stdout` - it doesn't just dump some info and exit.

If you want to use `top`, look at the man page. In particular, the `-b` option:

```
  -b  :Batch-mode operation
        Starts top in 'Batch' mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the  iterations  limit  you've  set
        with the '-n' command-line option or until killed.
```

So try `top -b -n 1` to get a single "batch" of info from `top`, then parse that.